# Hiding Drupal admin

Tags: drupal-7, apache2

I'm trying to hide my Drupal7 admin pages from the Internet, only allowing access from internal lan's.

I'm trying to hide /admin /user and */edit, but is there anything else I need to deny, to disable access to all parts of the Drupal admin?

```
<Location ~ "(/([aA][dD][mM][iI][nN]|[uU][sS][eE][rR])|/[eE][dD][iI][tT])">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all  
  Allow from 12.193.10.0/24
</Location>
```

Apache seems to accept this, and urlencoding chars in the request seems to be resolved before the request is handled (e.g.: /%55ser)

Edit: I've noticed parameterized paths, so I'm going to check for these kinds also: ?q=admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than those you've listed, the `*/delete` pages for one.

Modules can tell Drupal that certain paths (other than those beginning `admin/`) are supposed to be administrative by implementing [`hook_admin_paths()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7).

You can invoke the same hook to get a list of all the patterns that should be treated as administrative, and update your vhost file accordingly:

```
$paths = module_invoke_all('admin_paths');
```

A devel printout of the `$paths` variable looks like this:

[image]

It should give you a pretty good idea of the paths you need to hide. The printout will probably look completely different for your installation, it depends what modules you have installed.

Comment: Thanks Clive. Really usefull info.